# Beid : C# CryptoAcquireFailed Error=80090019

Tags: c#, cryptography

I'm using Belgian ID card to sign some stuff. The example `sign_csp` in the SDK failed with this error : `CryptoAcquireFailed. Error=80090019`.

```
//Get a context
if (!CryptAcquireContext(out hprov, container, provider, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
{
   MessageBox.Show("CryptAcquireContext failed.\n\n(Error=" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString("x") + ")"); 
   return;
}
```

provider = "Belgium Identity Card CSP"

I'm on Windows 7 64 bit. The program is built for x86.

Thanks!

Comment: err.exe says 0x80090019 = NTE_KEYSET_NOT_DEF, and [KB238187](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238187) says "The Crypto Service Provider (CSP) may not be set up correctly. Use of Regsvr32.exe on CSP DLLs (Rsabase.dll or Rsaenh.dll) may fix the problem, depending on the provider being used." Have you tried regsvr-ing the Beid DLLs?

Comment: yes but i had an error with the dll...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed the CSP correctly?

Verify that you have the following key in the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider\Belgium Identity Card CSP
```

and that the `Image Path` entry contains the correct path to the CSP-dll.