# CryptoAPI AcquireContext fails to retrieve key container

Tags: c#, .net, cryptoapi

I am porting an old VB6 application to .NET and I am having an issue since yesterday afternoon with some CryptoAPI calls.

In particular I can't retrieve a key container which is already defined. I use the `CryptAcquireContext()` function. I use some test code where I create the container. Then If I go to `C:\Users...\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\Machine Keys\` I can see a file created with my defined container name inside so I assume it's created successfully.

A subsequent call to try creating the same container verifies that assumption because I get the win32 error that the keyset is already defined.

Anyway on my next code call where I try to retrieve the container I already created I get the windows error that the keyset is not defined.

> Error : -2146893799 (80090019)    The keyset is not defined.

Any ideas?

Here's a code example :

```
public const uint PROV_RSA_FULL = 1;
public const uint CRYPT_NEWKEYSET = 0x00000008;
public const uint CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET = 0x00000020;
const string MS_DEF_PROV = "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0";

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool CryptAcquireContext(out IntPtr phProv, string pszContainer, string pszProvider, uint dwProvType, uint dwFlags);

public static void CreateContainer()
{
        IntPtr hCryptProv;
        int error;
        if (!CryptAcquireContext(out hCryptProv, "new", MS_DEF_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_NEWKEYSET))
        {
            error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }

        if (!CryptAcquireContext(out hCryptProv, "new", MS_DEF_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET))
        {
            error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
}
```

Comment: try not to use CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET when acquiring, instead use 0.

Comment: creating link to associated material which others may find helpful as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826390/beid-c-sharp-cryptoacquirefailed-error-80090019

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating key container for that user, but trying to get it from machine-based storage. To fix the problem you need either change `CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET` to 0 or when creating keyset use `CRYPT_NEWKEYSET | CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET` according to your needs.

> By default, keys and key containers are stored as user keys. For Base Providers, this means that user key containers are stored in the user's profile. A key container created without this flag by an administrator can be accessed only by the user creating the key container and a user with administration privileges.

For details, please check the links below.

[CryptAcquireContext() use and troubleshooting](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238187)

[CryptAcquireContext function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked. Although I don't quite understand the concept :(